# KendoMobile UI template with query strings

Tags: kendo-ui

UPDATE -

```
    <script id="clientEvals-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">

    <ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset">

        <li>
            <a href="\\#view-evalDetail?user_id=${client_id}&amp;eval_id=${eval_id}">${entry_stamp}</a>
        </li>

    </ul>

</script>
```

It seems that chars like the ? and the = contained in a kendomobile template break the local link

ie this WONT work:

```
        <ul data-role="list-view">

        <li><a href="\\#view-evalDetail?eval_id=${eval_id}">${entry_stamp}</a></li>

        </ul>

    </script>
```

But this WILL work (without the query string

```
    <script id="clientEvals-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">

        <ul data-role="list-view">

        <li><a href="\\#view-evalDetail">${entry_stamp}</a></li>

        </ul>

    </script>
```

Ive tried escaping this with mutiple chars ie \ \ // etc.. with now luck

Anyone know how to format this so that the local view is found WITH the query string?

Comment: Query string should appear before the hash. http://www.example.com/page?foo#bar is the correct. http://www.example.com/page#bar?foo is incorrect.

Comment: This is a kendo UI mobile view template so the <li><a href="\\#view-evalDetail">${entry_stamp}</a> works fine ... its when i add the query string vars ?eval_id=${eval_id} that kendo then treats the link as remote instead of local .. actually just adding the ? does the same thing

Comment: As I said query string parameters must appear before the hash.

Comment: @AtanasKorchev - PLEASE read my comment Icenium Templates REQUIRE \\#view-name to function properly, your comment only applies to standard HTML etc.. NOT to Icenium, please dont comment on things that you are not familiar with, it clouds up the site... THIS WORKS IN ICENIUM TEMPLATES a href="\\#view-evalDetail">${entry_stamp}</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the fix is to format all ampersands using html encoding inline, in any icenium template script areas

ie.

```
<!-- always use inline html encoding in icenium template scripts ie. &amp; -->


        <script id="clientEvals-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">

        <ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset">

            <li>
                <a href="\\#view-evalDetail?user_id=${client_id}&amp;eval_id=${eval_id}">${entry_stamp}</a>
            </li>

        </ul>

    </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

This was a known issue, it was resolved in the current service pack release.

Comment: Sorry i was wrong - not fixed - all ampersands need html encoding see answer below

Comment: I mentioned that the problem is resolved in the **current Kendo UI service pack** release -  [a jsbin](http://jsbin.com/aligem/46/edit) that demonstrates correct passing of multiple parameters, and their correct recognition from the view event handler.

Comment: Not sure we are on the same page :)